# Raising Me.Click in a custom user control (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, raiseevent

**Hi**,
I've been working on a custom control library for all my applications, but I also want it to be Open Source, so it needs to be easy to use.

I want to use the Me.Click event so when you click on `Panel1` (Panel) or `BtnText` (Label) it will raise the event `Click`, but for some reason it doesn't let me use that event in `RaiseEvent`.

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub BtnText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnText.Click
    RaiseEvent Click()
End Sub

Public Sub Panel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.Click
    RaiseEvent Click()
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you declare a Click event?  if it will be released, you might want to use the standard event signature: `sender As Object, e As EventArgs` like the clicks you are consuming

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, It said i had to make it a shadow, so i did and it worked.

Comment: Since the UC already has such an event, your custom one might be `ItemClick` or some such.  Be sure they can tell *what* was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To propagate the event to the **UserControl** you can invoke the **OnClick** method:

```
Public Sub BtnText_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnText.Click
    Me.OnClick(e)
End Sub

Public Sub Panel1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.Click
    Me.OnClick(e)
End Sub
```